# Grails: Can a config item(BuildConfig.groovy) inside environments block override a generic configuration?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

On my BuildConfig.groovy, I have:

```
grails.plugin.location.plugin1 = "../plugin1"
grails.plugin.location.plugin2 = "../plugin2"

environments {
    qa2-bamboo {
        grails.plugin.location.plugin1 = "../AGP-CON-PLUG/plugin1"
        grails.plugin.location.plugin2 = "../AGP-CON-PLUG/plugin2"
    }
}
```

When I'm in `qa2-bamboo`. Is `grails.plugin.location.plugin1 == "../AGP-CON-PLUG/plugin1"`?

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Bamboo+variables#comment-thread-289277097

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not supported, but it probably should be for consistency. You can access the current environment value though, so you can do this with if checks

```
import grails.util.Environment

if (Environment.current == Environment.DEVELOPMENT || Environment.isDevelopmentMode()) {
   ...
}
```

or a switch block:

```
switch (Environment.current) {
   case Environment.DEVELOPMENT:
      ...
      break
   case ...
   default:
      ...
}
```

Comment: So I can override this way, right? Or I've to repeat inside the case blocks?

Comment: And how do I use the switch statement for my custom environments? Thanks!